# Does anyone know what this component is?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage-regulator, identification

I've tried googling it and searching some datasheet sites, but I can't find it.

[image: microcontroller]

It's a chip in [this LCD screen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0045IIZKU). The reason I want to know is that the board can run at 5 V, but has a regulator to make it run from a 12 V cigarette lighter. I'm trying to make it run from USB at 5 V, so I need to desolder the voltage regulator.

Comment: While it is usually great to see a part in really close up to identify it and cut off the fluff, in such cases (the numbers often don't mean much) it is useful to *additionally* have more context, e.g. in the form of a (partial) schematic.

Comment: What kind of device is it mounted on ? Where is it located on the board ? What kind of components are around it ? ...

Comment: Also, why do you want to know? You need to put more effort into the question to get an answer even close to useful. Please edit the question and add more information, to avoid down votes and/or closure.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail.  It's a chip on this screen: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0045IIZKU .  The reason I want to know is that the board can run at 5v but has a regulator to make it run from a 12v cigarette lighter.  I'm trying to make it run from USB on 5v, so I need to desolder the voltage regulator.

Comment: I've added the info to the question itself.  Thanks @Asmyldof

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is this : [http://www.3peakic.com.cn/resources/download/TP2011-2012-2014_Rev1.0.pdf](https://www.3peakic.com.cn/resources/download/TP2011-2012-2014_Rev1.0.pdf)

Low power dual comparator - see the "Marking information" column in the table on p.2. (Found via google by including the package type, SOIC-8 in the search).

If pin 4 is Gnd and pin 8 is V+ (3.3 or 5V) that would be one vote for this part. (Pin 4 looks like a Gnd connection).

If it's in low power equipment and the surrounding circuitry needs a comparator, that would be another.

If the outputs (pins 1,7) connect to logic inputs on a MCU it's starting to look like a good fit.

Over to you, and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is its a comparator made by 3peak [here](http://www.3peakic.com.cn/resources/download/TP2011-2012-2014_Rev1.0.pdf) is the datasheet. 
If I'm right I'll tell you how I found it. You need more of a picture, it helps to see the components around it. I can see some resistors though and I see a power cap on pin 4 so this leads me to believe that it is an opamp or comparitor.